# Problema Windows 8.1 método App.GetResourceStream

Tags: string, xml, windows-phone-8-1

Estou com um problema em um método no windows phone. Ele faz a leitura de um arquivo xml e retorna uma string, o problema é que esse método só funciona no windows 8 e não no windows 8.1. Segue o código:

```
public static String readFile(String path)
        {
            var resource = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
            String arquivo = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return arquivo;
        }
```